# Properties of functions with specific properties

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question concerning positive-valued functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ with following properties:

- $\lim_\limits{{x \to \pm \infty}}f(x) =0$
- $\lim_\limits{{x\to \pm \infty}}f(x) - xf'(x)=0$.

Do they have any specific form? Specific properties in the tails?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: My first idea was to see if the second condition, interpreted as an asymptotically valid ODE $f(x) \sim x f'(x)$   ($\sim$ means asymptotically equal) gives any hint, but its solutions $f(x)\sim Ax$ require $A=0$ by the first condition. Actually the convergence to zero under these conditions may be very slow, for example $f(x) = \frac{1}{\ln(2+x^2)}$ satisfies all conditions and also $f(x) = o(1/x^\alpha)$, for all $\alpha>0$